# Determine all directional derivatives of a function for a circle

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> > A function $f: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is given by $$f(x,y)=6x^2y-x^3y-xy^3+2y^3+x^2-10xy+y^2-4x+4y+2$$
> >     Given the circle $C=\{(x,y) | (x-2)^2+y^2=2\}$. Imagine a point moving around C counter clockwise. **Determine for each position of this point the directional derivative of f in the point and the direction the point is moving in**

How can this be approached?

Comment: Where do you get stuck?

Comment: @user251257 - I am confused as where to begin...

Comment: If you are not sure, always starts with the definition.

Comment: Well the vector giving the direction the point is moving in is the unit tangent vector $T(t) = \dfrac{r'(t)}{|r'(t)|}$ for the curve you have which is easily described by a single parameter $t$ or even $\theta$